# php not working with email form

Tags: php

my email form doesn't seem to wanna work it just keeps coming back with the php form instead of the message it should 
here is the html part of the form

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                <p>The band would love to hear form you!</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="row moveMe3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="contact-form"> 
                    <form id="contact" method="post" action="process.php">
                        <fieldset>  
                            <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" title="Enter your name" class="required">
                            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" title="Enter your e-mail address" class="required email">
                            <label for="message">Question/Comment</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btnMove" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div><!-- /end #contact-form -->

            <div id="response"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contactus" id="moveMe2">
            <img src = "images/envalope.jpg" alt="Contact" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
```

here is the the first php that goes with it

```
<?php
// Get Data 
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Please Enter Your Name!<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>");
$email = check_input($_POST['email'], "Please Enter Your Email Address!<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>");
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Please Enter Your Message!<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>");


//Email Validation

    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
    {
      die("We're Sorry, but something went wrong please chenck it over and try again.");
    }

  //Function Check to Eliminate Unwanted Characters, Strips Quotes, and Adds HTMLSpecialCharacters

    function check_input($data, $problem='')
    {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
      {
         die($problem);
      }
      return $data;
    }

  //Spammer Check

    $email = urldecode($email);
    if (eregi("\r",$email) || eregi("\n",$email))
    {
      die("Spammer Detected");
    }

  //Sends Email and Forwards to Thank You Page

    mail( "preshesgirl@yahoo.com", $subject, $message, "From: $name <$email>" );
    header( "Location: thankyou.php" );

?>
```

here is the second php that goes with it

```
<?php
include('header.php');
?>
<?php
include('nav.php');
?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="response"></div> 
        <div class="contactus" id="moveMe2">
          <h1>We will get back to you soon!</h1>
             <img src="images/thanks.jpg" title="Thank you" alt="Thank you" class="img-responsive">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: it wont let me add my java script that goes with it but here it is

Comment: Use http://pastebin.com/ to post your javascript and some one will update it into your question. Also describe better what comes back, how it does not work.

Comment: Sidenote: [`eregi()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) `This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.`

Comment: Are you testing this on localhost or on a hosted web page?

Comment: my javascript is to long to post and when it comes back as a error it just comes back as the process.php form it doesn't render it like its suppost to

Comment: so your'e saying the PHP itself is in the response, as if the PHP isn't even being interpreted?

Comment: i am on a hosted webpage form my school but it still comes back with the error

Comment: yes that is correct the php itself is the responce let me add it to the server and give you the link

Comment: Sidenote: It should be if(strlen($data) == 0) instead of if($problem && strlen($data) == 0). $problem will always be true in your case.

Comment: http://inetstudent1.francistuttle.com/kp0938972/web_authoring_languages/discography/contact.html

Comment: now when clicking submit it comes back a thing acting like it sent but i never get the email

Comment: Sounds like a different question to me

Comment: that did nothing when changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the php variables with the string opposed to having the names of the variables being interpreted as part of the string.

Check process.php

```
mail( "preshesgirl@yahoo.com", $subject, $message, "From: ".$name." <".$email.">" );
```

It Was:

```
mail( "preshesgirl@yahoo.com", $subject, $message, "From: $name <$email>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked with php mail function for some big applications. Below are 2 points:

1) Always try to use a library like swiftmailer or phpmailer. They are built with ultimate features and its easy to debug. I understand your school application might be a small one and wont require a library. So i leave this judgement on you.

2) mail() returns boolean. So if you use something like:

```
try{
    @ mail(......);
} catch (Exception $e){}
```

This will not help you to catch errors. It will just say if the server accepted to process your request or not. It might display success to an undelivered email.

================================

If you can catch the error with die() and echo statements, you are good, else check your mail configuration on php.ini . Create a test php page and just write:

```
mail('xxx@example.com','subject','content')
```

Check if this works. If not, you have problem in the server.